# Performance of instantiating many prefabs as children of one prefab in unity

Tags: unity, performance, instancing

Is there any performance difference between **[instantiate multiple prefabs]** and **[put all prefabs under a single parent prefab and then instantiate that parent prefab]** in scene.
Hope you understand what i want to say.

Comment: The usual answer to performance questions is "profile it on your target platform and find out!" You can set up a synthetic test where you spawn thousands of objects each way, and examine the average time for each method over multiple trials (to control for unrelated hiccups).

Comment: Is that work if i print Time.time before and after instantiating prefab thousand time in loop. Just guess

Comment: Time.time probably won't have the resolution to get an accurate test, since it's only updated once each (physics/rendering) frame, and will include noise unrelated to the instantiation workload like rendering, vsync, and other scripts/processes. Consider either using [Unity's built-in profiler](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html), which will tell you how many ms each script took to run, or using your own instrumentation like [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DMGregory.
I've got an answer so I post it.
When I instantiate multiple(20000) individual prefabs(using loop 20000 times) at once in my scene,
I get (**573.73 to 463.63** Time ms and **43.81 to 30.63** Self ms)
but when I put 20 child prefabs to single parent and then instantiate parent prefab 1000 times in loop,
I get (**290.18 to 290.00** Time ms and **2.93 to 2.92** Self ms)
So, second way is better and efficient for my case.